# Cannot convert from 'initializer-list' to 'std::initializer_list<Keyword> &'

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, initializer-list

I'm trying to use an initialization-list to pass a list of keywords to a tokenizer to register. But it does not work in Visual Studio 2013. It works in gcc at ideone.com. Is there any way to use this or a similar syntax in VS?

```
struct Keyword
{
    const char* name;
    int id;
};

void AddKeywords(int group, std::initializer_list<Keyword>& lis) {}

// usage
AddKeywords(ITEM_TYPE, {
    { "weapon", IT_WEAPON },
    { "armor", IT_ARMOR }
});
```

Full error:

```
item.cpp(810): error C2664: 'void AddKeywords(int,std::initializer_list<Keyword> &)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'initializer-list' to 'std::initializer_list<Keyword> &'
```

Comment: That shouldn't compile anyway as rvalues cannot bind to non-const lvalue references.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How come a non-const reference cannot bind to a temporary object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are trying to bind a temporary to a non-const reference;

```
std::initializer_list<Keyword>& lis
```

Try either;

```
std::initializer_list<Keyword> const& lis
```

Or

```
std::initializer_list<Keyword> lis
```

When building with GCC, enable `-Wall -pedantic` it should give you an error then as well.